# Reading the file and writing the line length and character position. Why alternate lines get processed?

Tags: bash, line

My temp.txt file contains this :-

```
 x [deleted]         (none)     -> origin/redeem_deal0
 x [deleted]         (none)     -> origin/redeem_deal1
 x [deleted]         (none)     -> origin/redeem_deal2
 x [deleted]         (none)     -> origin/redeem_deal3
```

Writen a code to get the position of / and line length, of each line.

```
cat temp.txt | while read line
do
    echo $line    
    LINE_LEN="$(line | wc -c)"
    echo $LINE_LEN
    POS_FWD_SLASH=$(line | grep -b -o / | awk 'BEGIN {FS=":"}{print$
    echo $POS_FWD_SLASH
done
```

Outputs :-

```
manish@rigved:~/beawel/wwwnew$ /bin/sh deleted.sh 
 x [deleted]         (none)     -> origin/redeem_deal0

55
41
 x [deleted]         (none)     -> origin/redeem_deal3

1
```

---

If i comment out code from LINE_LEN to echo, and leave only "echo $line" it prints all 4 lines. But not with the code as above. Kindly help i wish to process all the 4 lines.

Answer (score 0):

`${#str}` gives length of `$str` no need for `wc -c`.

Whenever you have a while loop over a file, you should stop and consider if awk is the tool for you:

```
% awk '{print $0 RS length($0) RS index($0, "/")};' temp.txt
 x [deleted]         (none)     -> origin/redeem_deal0
54
42
 x [deleted]         (none)     -> origin/redeem_deal1
54
42
 x [deleted]         (none)     -> origin/redeem_deal2
54
42
 x [deleted]         (none)     -> origin/redeem_deal3
54
42
```

Comment: In the shell script wish to extract each "redeem_dealx" in a variable and process it further. So, i need to do line by line processing.